# Определить причину неработоспособности кода, нужен рефакторинг?

Tags: javascript

Такой код имеет право на жизнь? Прошу помочь с ошибкой и указать как надо правильно организовать код используя приведенные методы и переменные. Не получается закончить до логического результата. Ошибка в консоли: `Uncaught TypeError: newArr.map is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.handler`

1. Объединить значения в одну строку и разбить их по пробелу на массив строк.
2. Создать новый массив методом .map в котором обработать каждый элемент из массива newArr (в моем случае ищу подстроки регулярным выражением и помечаю их css-стилем подстрока), а также делаю в верхнем регистре.
3. Вывести результат на страницу, каждый элемент массива с новой строки.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit'); //записал в переменную кнопку "Отправить"
submit.addEventListener('click', handler); //добавляем событие и обработчик

//блок кода отвечает за обработку кнопок "закрыть" само событие расположено вот так "onclick="removeParent(this);" Откуда "e"?
function removeParent(e) { //обработчик
  var parentElem = e.parentNode; //определяем родителя
  parentElem.parentNode.removeChild(parentElem); //удаляем элемент
}

function handler() { //начало функции-обработчика
  var data = document.getElementById('in_1c').value; //получил и записал в переменную данные из textarea, тип данных "строка"
  var position = document.querySelector('.container'); //записал в переменную родителя
  //проверка, если поле textarea не пустое, то вставить и вывести данные, иначе сообщение об ошибке
  if (data != 0) {
    //объеденил все элементы в строку и разбил объект по пробелу на массив строк   
    var newArr = data.split(/\s/).join(' '); // тип данных "объект"(массив)
    
    //создаю новый массив методом .map в котором обрабатываю каждый элемент из массива newArr (в моем случае ищу подстроки регулярным выражением и помечаю их css-стилем <span class="red">подстрока</span>)
    var updateData = newArr.map(function(el) {
      var elements = el.replace(/([а-яё])/ig, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
      return elements.innerHTML = elements.toUpperCase();
    });


    position.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="removeParent(this);">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="data"><li>${updateData}</li></ul>
                </div>
              `);
  } else { //сообщение об ошибке
    var warningEl = document.createElement('div'); //создание элемента
    warningEl.setAttribute('class', 'warning'); //создание атрибута
    var message = document.createTextNode('Пожалуйста, заполните соотвествующие поля для обработки!'); //создание текстового узла
    warningEl.appendChild(message); //закрепляем текстовый узел в созданном элементе
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]; //получил в переменную родительский элемент
    e.appendChild(warningEl); //установка нового элемента на заданную позицию (по умолчанию ставится в конец)

  }
}
//конец функции обработчика события



//**очищение полей без перезагрузки**//
function resetValue1() {
  textArea = document.getElementById('in_1c');
  textArea.value = "";

}

function resetValue2() {
  textArea = document.getElementById('in_price');
  textArea.value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h2 class="header">Обработчик</h2>
       <!--<form action="">-->
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"><!--d-flex-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="in_1c">Номенклатура из 1С (например: RS-CS18AX/RU-18AX1)</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="in_1c" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <p class="text-right mt-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick="resetValue1();" value="Очистить"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="in_price">Номенклатура из прайса</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="in_price" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <p class="text-right mt-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick="resetValue2();" value="Очистить"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Отправить</button></div>
             </div>
        <!--</form>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в этой строчке:

```
//объеденил все элементы в строку и разбил объект по пробелу на массив строк   
var newArr = data.split(/\s/).join(' '); // тип данных "объект"(массив)
```

1. Метод [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) возвращает строку, а не объект и не массив. Он здесь лишний
2. `Объединил` пишется через **и**

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j9wlfn - почему не окрашивает в цвет найденные символы?